# How to pass a buffer into the Node 'crypto' module

Tags: node.js, hash, cryptography

I am using a `react` module called `react-dropzone`. When the user drops a file, it returns a `File`, which is a type of `blob`.

My goal is to find the sha-256 hash of this file. To do this I am trying to take the `File`, convert it into a `buffer` then feed the `buffer` to the `crypto` module. Here is the code I am using:

```
  handleOnDrop = file => {
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = event => {
        this.externalScopeVariable = event.target.result;
      };
      const buffer = fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

      hash.update(buffer);
      console.log(hash.digest("hex"));
    });
  };
```

I am getting the error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` coming from the `sha.js` node module.

Any help on how to accomplish the task of successfully hashing the `File` is a huge help. Thanks

Comment: Method `readAsArrayBuffer` is asynchronous and is not supposed to return value, so `buffer` will be always undefined. You need to move code below `readAsArrayBuffer` call into `onload` event handler.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the last sentence of your response is unclear to me, would you mind clarifying? Thank you

Comment: Huh, that was even pretty clear to me, somebody who never works with JS. You need to call `update` in the `onload` handler. `buffer` is undefined, as `readAsArrayBuffer` isn't defined to return any result.

Comment: yes, thank you. If you are curious, answer is here>>>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050401/how-to-use-filereader-with-react-getting-a-strange-error